# Python/Django png,gif to jpg

Tags: python, django, jpeg, python-imaging-library

i'm using Django 1.6.2 and Python 3.3.5 and Pillow 2.3.0.

What is the best way to convert an png/gif image to an jpg image in Django, so that the output-file is nearly the same as the uploaded file? (transparency => white)

I have tried a couple of solutions like:

```
import Image
im = Image.open("infile.png")
im.save("outfile.jpg")
```

or

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("file.png")
bg = Image.new("RGB", im.size, (255,255,255))
bg.paste(im,im)
bg.save("file.jpg")
```

The problem is i found no satisfied solution which handles gif, png (hard-edged mask, soft-edged mask).

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Ok, i'm using [ImageKit](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit), what does exactly what i want to do.

Comment: FYI, JPG does not support any kind of transparency.

Comment: And GIF doesn't support alpha transparency, like PNG does.

Comment: `no satisfied solution which handles all kind of files`??

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("file.png")
bg = Image.new("RGB", im.size, (255,255,255))
bg.paste(im, (0,0), im)
bg.save("file.jpg", quality=95)
```

- Passing in the second image in `bg.paste(im, (0,0), im)` allows im's
  alpha channel to act as a mask over your background image.
- The coordinates `(0,0)` paste your
  image perfectly over your background
- `bg.save("file.jpg", quality=95)`; `quality=95` ensures the highest quality from `PIL`

Comment: It works on png files. When im trying to upload an gif the following Exception will be thrown: `Exception Type:ValueErrorException Value:bad transparency mask`

Comment: can you upload your mask so I can try the error myself? Anymore detail on the error?

Comment: Here my example gif: http://www.funnyjunk.com/funny_gifs/4260026/Pokemon+Gif  The error occurs in `self.im.paste(im, box, mask.im)`