# how to convert image type from GIF to PNG/JPG in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to convert the image type from gif to png or jpg using python

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('upload.gif')
transparency = im.info['transparency'] 
im.save('test1.png', transparency=transparency)

im.seek(im.tell()+1)
transparency = im.info['transparency'] 
im.save('test2.png', transparency=transparency)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python/Django png,gif to jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110761/python-django-png-gif-to-jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
def iter_frames(im):
    try:
        i= 0
        while 1:
            im.seek(i)
            imframe = im.copy()
            if i == 0: 
                palette = imframe.getpalette()
            else:
                imframe.putpalette(palette)
            yield imframe
            i += 1
    except EOFError:
        pass

for i, frame in enumerate(iter_frames(im)):
    frame.save('test%d.png' % i,**frame.info)
```

You can check out this link and answer by @DSM:

[Python: Converting GIF frames to PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904940/python-converting-gif-frames-to-png)